Data Access in Blazor Web Apps
I'm trying to make a decision between the new Blazor Web App in .NET 8 and the stand alone Blazor WASM option. I'm not quite clear about getting data in the new unified approach.
Do Blazor Web Apps always call an API end point via an HttpClient or is there a direct way to get data, similar to the MVC approach?
I understand that one of the main advantages of the new Web App model is quick rendering of pages/components due to the flexible options it provides e.g. server rendering, streaming, etc. which means there's a server that runs .NET. If that's the case being able to fetch data without the need to serialize/deserialize would be a benefit OR is it always a call to an API endpoint then deserialize data. Just wondering how this is handled in the unified Blazor approach.

Yes, you have two options.
Using the API approach in both modes is the simplest.
If you want to implement the server side option you need to design your data pipeline to do so.  Basically use a interface based data broker that has different implementations for different end points.
A description on how to do so is beyond the scope of a SO answer, but there's a document I wrote on the subject [in the early days of Net8] here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/An-Interactive-Data-Pipeline.md.
